# Adding API documentation on WSO2 3.2.0 using apictl

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there a way to **add/upload** API documentation using apictl tool? After `apictl init`, I tried copying the Documentation files to the Docs -> FileContents directory and after importing the project `apictl import-api` the Docs are **not** visible on the Developer/publisher portal.

Apart from **UI** and **Rest** call, is there any other way of publishing API docs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can upload the documentation using apictl.

If you want to upload a .pdf or any file as a document, you need to add it to the **FileContents** folder. But if you want to add an inline document or a markdown content, you need to the **InlineContents** folder.

Another important thing is that, you need to include **docs.yaml** file with the details of your documents inside the **Docs** directory. For example, the **Docs** directory structure should be as shown below.

```
Docs
├── docs.yaml
├── FileContents
│   └── test file document.pdf
└── InlineContents
    └── Doc1
```

For more information refer the example **docs.yaml** file below.

```
-
  type: HOWTO
  name: Doc1
  summary: test
  sourceType: INLINE
  visibility: API_LEVEL
 -
  type: HOWTO
  name: Doc2
  summary: file test
  sourceType: FILE
  visibility: API_LEVEL
  filePath: test file document.pdf
```

In the **docs.yaml** file you need to specify the details of your documents as an array as shown above. The above is an example that I created to import 2 documents. The 1st doc is an **inline** doc and the 2nd one is a **file**.

You can refer to the full API artifact which I created with docs [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/do2icz5y0bzhvkm/AABLNOf3o5P2nlz4PDrTAesPa?dl=0) that is compatible with APICTL 3.2.1 and APIM 3.2.0.

**Tip:-** If you want to be more sure, create an API with documents using the UI as we normally do. Export the particular API using the `apictl export-api` command. Then, check the **Docs** directory of the exported API archive to get an idea.

**UPDATE (2nd May 2021)**: Refer to the link [here](https://wasuradananjith.medium.com/a-remedy-to-manage-api-documentation-using-wso2-api-controller-4d501d2809db) to learn how to manage your API documentation using WSO2 API Controller as a step by step guide.

Comment: Edited this on 2nd May 2021 by adding a link to learn how to manage your documentation using the WSO2 API Controller (https://wasuradananjith.medium.com/a-remedy-to-manage-api-documentation-using-wso2-api-controller-4d501d2809db)